# The dependency injection (di) paradigm with 3rd party libraries in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I am trying to create Aurelia custom element using React, by following this example on [Aurelia Q & A](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/02/03/aurelia-qa/) and following exception occurs:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [1] TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
```

What I am doing wrong? Here my test code:

**test.html**

```
<import from="./myelement"></import>
<my-element foo.bind="Value"></my-element>
```

**myelement.html**

```
<template>
  <input type="text" placeholder="user">
</template>
```

**myelement.js**

```
import {Behavior} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {React} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyElement {
  static metadata(){
    return Behavior
      .customElement('my-element')
      .withProperty('foo')
      .noView();
  }

  static inject() {
    return [Element];
  }

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    console.log('this:', this);
    console.log('element:', element);
  }

  bind() {
    // React.render(<MyReactElement foo={this.foo} />, this.element);
    React.render(React.createElement(MyReactElement, { foo: this.foo }), this.element);
  }

  fooChanged() {
    this.bind();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine `import {React} from 'aurelia-framework';` should actually be: `import {React} from 'react';`

Comment: right, `import React from 'react'` actually

Comment: yes, thanks. Reading the blog I assumed react used internally, not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick with importing third party libraries is you must choose how you wish to get access to the library.  In your case if you are trying to create a single custom element using react that combines a view and a view model you can do so simply like this -

`jspm install react`

and then inside your view model -

`import react from 'react'`

Then you can use it anywhere in your view model, such as -

```
attached(element){
  // React pseudo-code
  react.render(element);
}
```

If you choose to load the library through dependency injection so that it is available as a module anywhere you have more options, but I think this should give you a start.